# Laravel Forge store files/images with load balancer

Tags: laravel, load-balancing, laravel-forge

I have a question: I am looking to deploy my app to Laravel Forge. Now my app does save images locally on the server, but when I scale my app and add load balancers, I think saving images on different servers isn't a good practice.

Because when one server goes down, some of the images wont load for example.

How could I do this in a good manner?

Comment: How many images are you looking to save? It seems like using AWS S3 would be a good option to avoid any potential issues (with CloudFront if you're concerned with the speed in which they are retrieved)

Comment: @MatthewBradley like about 10 per user. And then another 50 or so that belongs to the app. But I will look at AWS S3 thanks!

Comment: With their free-tier for the first 12 months, this should more than cover what you're planning to do - and from there its very reasonable for storage.

Comment: Yeah, 100% AWS S3 or anything similar, it must be stored in the cloud